# Open ended cylinder not showing inside material

Tags: three.js

jsFiddle demonstrating problem: http://jsfiddle.net/calvintennant/nnm64/1/

Sources suggest that adding `mesh.flipSided = true` will render the material on the inside of a mesh, other [source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/388)s mention the use of `mesh.doubleSided = true` for showing the cylinder on both the inside and the outside. As demonstrated in my jsFiddle, these do not seem to work..

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As specified in the [migration](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) page, this changed between r49 and r50!

`object.flipSided` is now `material.side = THREE.BackSide`.
`object.doubleSided` is now `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide`.

Fixed jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nnm64/2/